# Understanding $(12)(23)=(132)$ in the symmetric group $S_3$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I am studying symmetric groups, as an example for the symmetric group $S_3$ I have the equality:

$$(12)(23)=(132)$$

It may be very trivial but I cannot derive it: how can this be done?

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/472787/81360) helpful

Comment: We have 

$$\begin{align}
1&\xrightarrow{(12)} 2\xrightarrow{(23)} 3,\\
3&\xrightarrow{(12)} 3\xrightarrow{(23)} 2,\\
2&\xrightarrow{(12)} 1\xrightarrow{(23)} 1.\\
\end{align}$$

This is evaluating from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the answer $(1\ 3\ 2)$, I assume that you are meant to compose these from left to right (contrary to the more common convention).

You might find the following figure to be helpful.

[image]

If anyone is curious, here is the code I used to generate this in Tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40}]
%"mystyle" is a variable that specifies the node's style when used as optional arg
  \foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3} 
      {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\i)}
      \node[mystyle]  (\i\j) at (6*\j,-1*\i) {\label};}

  \foreach \i [count = \ct] in {2,1,3}              %first permutation
    \draw[->,ultra thick,draw=red!70] (\ct 1)--(\i 2);
  \foreach \i [count = \ct] in {1,3,2}              %second permutation
    \draw[->,ultra thick,draw=olive] (\ct 2)--(\i 3);
  \node[draw] at (9,0) {$(1\ \ 2)$};
  \node[draw] at (15,0) {$(2\ \ 3)$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40}]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \j in {1,2} 
      {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{(\i)}
      \node[mystyle]  (\i\j) at (12*\j,-1*\i) {\label};}

  \foreach \i [count = \ct] in {3,1,2}
    \draw[->,ultra thick,draw=blue!70] (\ct 1)--(\i 2);
  \node[draw] at (18,-1) {$(1\ \ 2)(2\ \ 3)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```